# How to check if it is array of objects or array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to differentiate between an array of objects and an array of strings?
How do I determine which array is this?

It could be like this `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` or

It could be like `[ { foo: 'bar' }, { qux: 'quux' } ]` And I would like to handle them separately

Comment: Something like `typeof arrayOfSuspiciousEntities[0]` comes to mind.

Comment: Please use few more words to explain question better. probably an example would do

Comment: Just added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the first item of the array has any object properties.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var type = typeof(list1[0])
```

Simple

Answer (score 0):

In JS you can have an array of different data types. Because of this, you'd have to test each item in the array. What do you want to do with this array? That will determine what the code looks like.

Comment: It could be like this `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` or it could be like `[ { foo: 'bar' }, { qux: 'quux' } ]` And I would like to handle them separately

Comment: Noah Gerrad's answer is a good starting point, test the first item in the array using typeof myArray[0]

Answer (score 0):

You can loop this array via foreach or map method and by using operator typeof check type of every item in array.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way for me to find out what type of contents in the Array is to loop thru the array using the console.dir().  With console.dir see all the properties. You can add the typeof operator to find the type of a JavaScript variable in the console.dir()

```
const list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
const list2 = [ { foo: 'bar' }, { qux: 'quux' } ];

list.forEach(item => console.dir(item)); // output: foo, bar, baz
list2.forEach(item => console.dir(item)); //output: Object, Object
```

console.dir resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir